# how to attribute OpenStreetMap on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, openstreetmap, route-me

I would like to attribute OpenStreetMap on my app, but I can't find the code for that, I was hoping it would be on the samples. There should be a text on the map with a link to OpenStreetMap as shown in the image. Any ideas? or should I open a small webView just for that on the map?
I am using the [Routeme framework for iOS](https://github.com/route-me/route-me/tree/master/samples)

[image: OpenStreetMap]

Comment: First, you should consider switching to a more recent, supported branch. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk

Comment: Thanks! It has been so long, I wondered where everybody go